# Can I use the Chebychev inequality to prove this statement?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, stochastic-calculus

> Let $X$ be a random variable with $\Bbb{E}(X^2)<\infty$ and $a>0$ I need to show that $$\Bbb{P}(X>a)\leq \frac{\Bbb{E}(X^2)}{a^2}$$

My idea was the following. Let me first remark that $$\{X>a\}\subset \{|X-\Bbb{E}(X)|\geq a\}$$Indeed if $X>a>0$ then $|X|>a$. Now consider $a\leq|X-\Bbb{E}(X)|\leq |X|+|\Bbb{E}(X)|$. This is equivalent to say that $a-|X|<0\leq|\Bbb{E}(X)|$ which is always true. Therefore we have $$\Bbb{P}(X>a)\leq \Bbb{P}(|X-\Bbb{E}(X)|\geq a)\stackrel{\text{Chebychev}}{\leq}\frac{Var(X)}{a^2}=\frac{\Bbb{E}(X^2)-\Bbb{E}(X)^2}{a^2}\leq\frac{\Bbb{E}(X^2)}{a^2}$$

Is this proof correct so? I know there is maybe a simpler one, but this was the first thing coming to my mind so it would be nice if you first could take a look at this prove and then if it's correct discuss about alternatives

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is using what you want to prove as a step, actually: Chebyshev's is proven using Markov's, and what you need is basically that proof (using Markov's inequality). All you need is to apply Markov's to $\mathbb{P}\{X^2 > a^2\}$ (instead of  $\mathbb{P}\{|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|^2 > a^2\}$ as in the proof of Chebyshev's).

Comment: @ClementC. sorry where do I use what I want?

Comment: You are using Chebyshev, which is proven in a way which is basically what you're asked to show (this is what I tried to outline in my comment). So you're using the end statement to get what's essentially the proof of that statement.

Comment: @ClementC. ah okey I see but to be sure are there any mathematical errors so I mean argumental errors which I didn't see?

Comment: The `argumental' error is that you use the thing you are trying to prove.

Comment: Also, I don't see how the inclusion between events really holds. Suppose $X=2a$ almost surely. Then $\{X>a\}$ has probability one, but $\{|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|\geq a\}$ has probability 0.

Comment: @ClementC. I see. But I don't see where the argument of the inclusion between the sets fails

Comment: Your chain of inequalities doesn't prove the inclusion: if $X>a$, you can conclude that $|X|+|\mathbb{E}[X]|>a$ indeed, but that *doesn't* mean the thing in the middle, $|X - \mathbb{E}[X]|$, is also greater than $a$.

Comment: @ClementC. I see thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the result just use Markovs inequality as the other answer shows. In your proof you use the inequality you are trying to prove! Note you use Chebyshev inequality :

$$ P(|Y-\mu|\geq \sigma k)\leq \frac{1}{k^2}.$$

But if we define the centered random variable $X=Y-\mu$, then the above says (note $\text{Var}(Y)=\sigma$)

$$ P(|X| \geq \sigma k) \leq \frac{1}{k^2},$$

choose $k=\frac{a}{\sigma}$ gives

$$ P(|X| \geq a) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}. $$

You want to prove this last inequality, but as you can see it is equivalent to Chebyshevs inequality (so you cant you use Chebyshev to prove it).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a shorter path is this:
$$\mathbb{P}(X>a)\leq \mathbb{P}(|X|>a)=\mathbb{P}(X^2>a^2)\leq \frac{E(X^2)}{a^2}$$
The last inequality is trivial, for any nonnegative random variable $Y$ and $b>0$
$$E(Y)=\int_{Y>b}Y\,d\mathbb{P}+\int_{Y\leq b}Y\,d\mathbb{P}\geq b\,\mathbb{P}(Y>b)$$
As pointed out by Clement C. this trivial inequality is known as Markov's inequality.

Comment: The last inequality is trivial, but also has a name: Markov's inequality :)